# NSString String with format: position/ placement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

```
//Screen Size Label
if (_screenFontEnable) {
        [_sfColor set];
        NSString *canvasLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n W:%i/H:%i",_label,screenSizeWidth,screenSizeHeight ];
        [canvasLabel drawAtPoint:NSPointFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%i,%i}",boarder+(((screenSizeWidth/2)-_screenFontSize)),boarder+((screenSizeHeight/2)-_screenFontSize)]) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:screensize], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:_sfColor}];
}
```

Hello, so I am trying to center my text in center of rectangle drawn by user input in pixel it could be `100x100` or `1000x1000` as they prefer which comes in from `ScreenSizeWidth` or `ScreenSizeHeight`. Also user inputs `ScreenFontSize` which is printed on top of the drawn rect. `screenFontsize` changes, as well as screen size  so number of  characters that print in the rect changes.

I figured out how to place it center in vertical axis but can't figure out how to to do it horizontally.

The idea maybe to get width of screen size label somehow  and center with size of the rect width, but how to do this is beyond me.

here is what it prints on my current code from above - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeWdw.png)

Comment: try to break the code down a little give name to variables. Right now is hard to read. And if its hard to read you might not see obvious mistakes (not that i see one this is just a general suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the `NSString` methods:

```
- (NSSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *) attributes
- (NSRect)boundingRectWithSize:(NSSize)size
                       options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options
                    attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attributes
                       context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

to determine the length of your text when rendered and then do the math required to centre it.

HTH